# How do i get the sum of a dataframe with a specified conditions?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

i have the following dataframe headings :
Instrument  ClosedVolume    NetRevenue  TradePnL

In my trade data, I multiple trades of the same instrument which resulted in different TradePnL.

I will like to sum or if possible, reiterate all the different instruments in my data frame.

For example, I will like to get all the trade data of my Alibaba that makes positive TradePnL, what should I do?

```
    sum(df['TradePnL'] ) #should give me my tradePnL of all my trades

    df[df['Instrument'] == "Alibaba"] #this will give me all instruments data with Alibaba
```

Answer (score 1):

just combine the conditions with a binary and

`df[(df['Instrument'] == "Alibaba") & (df['TradePnL'] > 0)]`

I guess ...

or more likely

```
df[df['TradePnL'] > 0].groupby(['Instrument']).agg("sum")
```

select where PNL > 0, then group by instruments, and finally get the sum of positive pnls

Comment: Thank you Joran,
        df[df['TradePnL'] > 0].groupby(['Instrument']).agg("sum") #is exactly what i want!

Comment: how can I sort them in descending order?

Comment: df[df['TradePnL'] > 0].groupby(['Instrument']).agg("sum").sort_values(by ='TradePnL',ascending=False)